# vim getting split screen layout back after maximizing one split window

Tags: vim

So I did a vertical split and maximized one of the split window using CNTRL+| . Now how do I make it go back to the same size ?

EDIT: 
Let me elaborate my question , suppose I have a layout like this

```
------------------
| one     | two  |
|-----------------
|three    | Four |
------------------
```

In the above layout I maximize window three to capture entire screen size. Now if I  just want to have three and four in split view with "one" and "two" minimized,  how can that be done ?

Comment: I've used the ZoomWin VIM plugin for years, and it totally rocks.... I can maximize any window for a bit, then hit the same key and it goes back to my splits.... win! http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=508

Answer (score 7):

If you didn't do any resizing between the creation of the vertical split and `<C-w>|`, `<C-w>=` will return you to an "equalized" layout.

If you did some resizing you are out of luck as Vim doesn't keep a "resize history".

See `:help windows`.

Comment: <C-W>= would fail if there happens to be a horizontal split as it resizes all the splits equally!

Comment: There's no generic option/command for that. You should record a macro or write a command that does all the actions necessary to get your result.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just the two windows, Ctrl-W = will make both the same width again, but if you have more windows, their size might be affected by this, too. If you have mouse support (e.g. in GVIM), you also just drag around the window border to resize.